# Google Analytics: report on IP subnet

Tags: google-analytics

I am interested in knowing what percentage of my traffic comes from within the company. My company has its own subnet.

I'm not interested in **excluding** them, rather I want to compare their traffic to the rest of the traffic.

I thought of doing a Custom Report, but I don't see any "IP" metric.

I also tried to create a new "view", filtered by IP. Which seems to work (it does not work on previous data, so I can only look at real time data). However it does not allow to compare with the regular view, it's a standalone view it seems.

Comment: When people within your company access the site, I take it they use their public IP addresses, and not a private subnet like 10.* or 192.168.*? If they used a private subnet, google would see all their IP addresses as being the same (which I take it is not what's happening)?

Comment: Public IPs yes. For which I know the regex.